# Subclassing SHBrowseForFolder and handling WM_NOTIFY

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-shell

I'm trying to fix SHBrowseForFolder dialog, as it doesn't react on folder renaming (`BFFM_SELCHANGED` isn't being sent and there is no way to determine is the path now correct or not). I googled a solution, which said like I have to subclass dlg's wndproc and catch `TVN_ENDLABELEDIT` to send `BFFM_SELCHANGED` myself.

Here is how I set new wndproc when I get `BFFM_INITIALIZED`:

```
for (HWND hChild = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_CHILD); hChild != 0; hChild = GetWindow(hChild, GW_HWNDNEXT)) {
    szClassName[256];
    GetClassName(hChild, szClassName, sizeof(szClassName));
    if (!stricmp(szClassName, "SHBROWSEFORFOLDER SHELLNAMESPACE CONTROL")) {
        oldWndProc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(SetWindowLongPtr(hChild, GWLP_WNDPROC, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(_SubclassWndProc)));
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is _SubclassWndProc:

```
static LRESULT _SubclassWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM lParam, LPARAM lpData) {
  switch (uMsg) {
     case WM_NOTIFY:
        switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code) {
           case TVN_ENDLABELEDIT:
              break;
        }
        break;
  }
  return CallWindowProc(oldWndProc, hWnd, uMsg, lParam, lpData);
}
```

It works only if I comment `WM_NOTIFY` block. Even an access to `lParam` breaks dialog (it contains corrupted treee with empty labels). If I call oldWndProc before switch, then it works, but in `WM_NOTIFY` case `lParam` obviously doesn't contain a pointer to `NMHDR`, it contains a small integer value like 1,2,100 etc.

**Edit:** The question can be shortened to "Why does WM_NOTIFY come without a pointer to NMHDR?"

Comment: Are you sure your `_SubclassWndProc` signature matches that of `WNDPROC`? I would have expected the `CALLBACK` macro, but it can be okay if you use some other method of specifying the calling convention.

Answer (score 2):

The error was due to my negligence: I copied wndproc signature from some example, which has  agrument names confused. The lParam usually comes last and has a type LPARAM. So I was trying to cast arg usually called wParam, which contains a control id not LPNMHDR.

Comment: Heh, I had just posted that as an answer about 20 seconds after you figured it out already :)